# Laravel 9 Migration (Unit Testing)

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-9

I'm working on a Laravel 9 app, it has no migration files.
And when writing test cases, I got server error 500 and
`PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: {table-name} in /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:368`

I created test migration files and run them with its path but does not work

```
class AppTest extends TestCase {      
      use DatabaseMigrations;
      public function setUp(): void {
         parent::setUp();
         Artisan::call('migrate', ['--path' => base_path('tests/migrations/')]);
     }
}
```

How can I test the app without migration files, or is there another way?

Comment: Please, share your test and the part your test is running. Do you have models? If that is the case, you need to create and set your database somehow, you can achieve that with migrations or you can manually do so, but why would you don't have migrations?

Comment: @matiaslauriti
I created test migration files and run them with its path but does not work
`class AppTest extends TestCase {

    use DatabaseMigrations;

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        Artisan::call('migrate', ['--path' => base_path('tests/migrations/')]);
    }
}`

Comment: @AhmedAmshir: Edit your question, no need to splat things into a comment below it, its your question, make it beautiful ;)